# UILabel.center not setting when text has been modified or on view load

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm having a problem with the .center attribute of UILabels. I need to have a label move around depending on where my cursor is in my textView. My code looks like:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    if([[textView text] length] > 160){
        return NO;
    }

    //CharacterLimitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", 160 - [[textView text] length]];

    [self setCharacterLabelPosition];
    return YES;
}

-(void)setCharacterLabelPosition{
    CGPoint cursorPosition = [CreateTextView caretRectForPosition:CreateTextView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;
    cursorPosition.x = cursorPosition.x + CreateTextView.frame.origin.x + 45;
    cursorPosition.y = cursorPosition.y + CreateTextView.frame.origin.y + 15;

    CharacterLimitLabel.center = cursorPosition;
}
```

This works for the most part, however, when I uncomment the setting of the label, the label does not change its center at all anymore.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by setting that text to 160 - the number of characters?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I'm trying to show the amount of characters left that they can type.

Comment: @LyndseyScott It's supposed to be trailing after the cursor when they type, however, when setting the text, the position somehow goes back to the one in the storyboard.